# Sublime Text: How do I add a snippet that can excute keyboard shortcuts

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext4

I wanted to have a snippet that automatically adds the time and date to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with [snippets](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html), as they can't handle dynamically-generated data like datetimes. Instead, you need a [plugin](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/plugins/) to generate the information on the fly. Fortunately, some already exist in [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io).

[`Timenow`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Timenow) looks like a good one, although I haven't used it personally. I *have* used [`InsertDate`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/InsertDate) and really like it. It's very configurable and allows for time zone customization, among other features. It also has very good documentation.